# list in sidebar Menu with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and AngularJS and i have this code to make a sidebar Menu,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Link</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Active Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Link</a></li>

            <!-- Dropdown-->
            <li class="panel panel-default" id="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdown-lvl1">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sub Level <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>

                <!-- Dropdown level 1 -->
                <div id="dropdown-lvl1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                            <!-- Dropdown level 2 -->
                            <li class="panel panel-default" id="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdown-lvl2">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Sub Level <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <div id="dropdown-lvl2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> Link</a></li>

        </ul>
```

My problem is when i click on the sub level menu it redirects me to localhost/#dropdown-lvl1 instead of showing  the div dropdown-lvl1, any idea why  it has this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses the # in the url to do its routing, because you have `<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdown-lvl2">` it will try to go to that route, in order to scroll down on a page use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)